# Encrypting a column in SQL Server 2000 database

Tags: encryption, sql-server

I've been tasked with encrypting several years worth of sensitive data (don't ask) stored in a SQL Server 2000 Database.  I need to encrypt both historical data and come up with a process to encrypt and decrypt new data as it flows through the system.

Most of the solutions out there seem to use extened stored procedures that call dlls that must be installed on the server.

The best I've seen so far is [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Security/freeencryption/1980/), the tools are free but you have to register at the site.

Are there any better solutions out there?

Comment: This is probably a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: I wasn't sure, as it may involve adding libraries to an SQL Server instance, it seemed more Server Fault-ish?

Answer (score 3):

Why not upgrade to sql 2008?  Encryption is now built in and you'll get better performance on the same hardware.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing native in SQL Server 2000 that you can use.  Anything that you find will have an extended stored procedure which will need to be installed on the system in order to work.

Answer (score 0):

How about ROT13 twice... for double protection?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13

LOL... sorry... couldn't resist. ;-)

On a more serious note... are you trying to encrypt/decrypt in the SQL server itself, or are you planning on doing the encrypt/decrypt at the application level?

I know there are various solutions out there for SQL Server 2005 and 2008 but since you have SQL 2000 you might just find that doing it at the application level is less of a headache.

Comment: As some of the processes run on different platforms (that I don't have control over) an application level solution seems unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [Protegrity](http://www.protegrity.com/EncryptionAndHashing). I have used it successfully in a project and am quite happy with it.